# Extract block of line from file by delimiter

Tags: text-processing

Input.txt:

```
d1
a4
TEXT|VALUE1
TEXT|VALUE2
.
c8
TEXT|NVALUE1
.
a10
TEXT|VALUE3
.
a13
TEXT|VALUE4
.
c15
TEXT|NVALUE2
.
d20
d23
.
```

For file1, search for string start with `a[number]*` and stop at delimiter dot `.`.

For file2, string start with `c[number]*` and stop at delimiter dot `.`.

Expected outputs:

```
==> file1 <==
TEXT|VALUE1
TEXT|VALUE2
TEXT|VALUE3
TEXT|VALUE4

==> file2 <==
TEXT|NVALUE1
TEXT|NVALUE2
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```c
awk '
    $0 == "." { of = ""; next }
    $0 ~ /^a[0-9]+$/ { of = "file1"; next }
    $0 ~ /^c[0-9]+$/ { of = "file2"; next }
    of != "" { print >of }
' input.txt
```

Comment: That's assuming the shell meaning of `>>` rather than the awk meaning - it should be `>`, not `>>`. You don't need the `$`0 in `print $0` as that's the default.

Comment: @EdMorton Ah, thanks. Have always assumed `>>` was for appending in awk as well.

Comment: @ibuprofen It is for appending, but you use it when appending to files that exists before appending for the first time (or just after `close`). Using `>`  leaves the file open for writing, so subsequent `>` would not truncate the file (only the first would).

Comment: Idk if it makes things any clearer but - the semantics for `>` and `>>` in `print x > file` and `print x >> file` in awk are the same as these semantics for `>` and `>>` in shell: `while read x; do echo "$x"; done > file` and `while read x; do echo "$x"; done >> file` rather than `echo "$x" > file` and `echo "$x" >> file`